# Backing up multiple computers with Macrium Reflect - nested image files

Tags: backup, images, compression, imaging, macrium

I'm planning to back up 12 old computers and HDDs from my parent's collection. These are yet to fail despite their age. My method involves imaging the drives and partitions with default compression settings, one computer at a time. Each will be saved to individual folders on a 12 TB external HDD (External HDD #1). After this, I aim to create a redundant backup of 'External HDD #1' on another 12 TB drive (External HDD #2).

Here are my questions:

1. Are there any specific considerations or potential issues with backing up multiple .mrimg files from External HDD #1 to a single image file on External HDD #2? I'm not sure if "nested" image files is the correct term here, so any advice on this would be appreciated.
2. Should I use the default compression for this project, or opt for no compression? My concern is about Macrium Reflect possibly recompressing the already compressed image files when backing up External HDD #1 to External HDD #2.

I've tried to keep this explanation concise. Please let me know if any clarifications are needed.

Thank you for any assistance! I’m using Macrium Reflect Free v8.0.7279 but plan to update to v8.0.7690 before starting this project.

Comment: You should not put and image of drive1 on drive2, you should just make a copy of it

Comment: @Gantendo Thank you for your response. For ensuring the image files remain 100% identical, would you recommend using Robocopy, or would a simple copy and paste suffice?